# Error when trying to open new window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing a till system and I want to open a payment window where you finalise the payment but when I try to open the window it gives me the `System.ArgumentException: 'Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.'` error when I click the button to open the new window. here is my code :

```
  private void PaymentButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!PaymentWindowOpen)
            {
                PaymentWindow Window = new PaymentWindow(this);
                Window.Show();//this is where the error shows
                PaymentWindowOpen = true;
            }
        }
```

That is the code for the button.
Here is the code for the payment window class:

```
   public partial class PaymentWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        public PaymentWindow(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.mainWindow = mainWindow;
            PaymentPrice.Content = mainWindow.ActualTotal;

        }

        private void FiverButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Ignore the empty method, Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: As the error message says, `ActualTotal` can only appear *once*, i.e. you cannot display the same instance of a control in two different windows at the same time.

Comment: Is actual total not just a number? Just pass the value in and set a textblock.text to it.

Comment: @mm8 removing the ```PaymentPrice.Content = mainWindow.ActualTotal;``` fixed the problem,  could you show me properly how to show the total from the first window to the second?

Comment: @burnie5749: What kind of control is `ActualTotal`? If it's a `TextBox`, you'll find a solution below.

Comment: The field initialization which create another instance of main window inside payment window is another problem. Don't pass main window instance around. Create dedicated class (called model) to hold data, then create dedicated class to service user actions and model presentation (called view model) and start using commnds/bindings.. and you are already in a beautiful world of MVVM, where nothing can go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, `ActualTotal` can only appear once, i.e. you cannot display the same instance of a control in two different windows at the same time.

If `ActualTotal` is a TextBlock, you could copy the string value from its `Text` property rather than setting the `Content` of `PaymentPrice` to the `TextBlock` itself:

```
PaymentPrice.Content = mainWindow.ActualTotal.Text;
```